# Keeping file permissions with FTP

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

Is there a way I can upload my files from my computer to my server without losing the permissions? Everything is linux.

Thank you!

Comment: you can archive, use tar(--preserve-permissions) for that, then just transfer using whatever and then just untar it

Comment: how do do this for multiple dirs?

Comment: thats why you tar them. tar can create an archive from a directory which you can then happily transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all FTP clients (cute, filezilla, smart, yafc, etc) have the option to set file permissions.

I have not yet seen any feature / option to permanently persist the file permissions from your computer to the server. However you can in filezilla and in cuteftp ( i use these 2) set an advanced property which will auto apply a permission set of your choice to all files uploaded.

Also, i think this is not likely to ever be released as a feature since file permissions are also based on user! Different users on your computers and different users on your server all of which may or may not have differing permissions.

Hope this helped. Cheers.

PS: let me know if you can't find the option in filezilla or cuteftp

Comment: cant find option in filezilla

Comment: for that you have a checkbox option 'recurse into subdirectories'

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that ftp is not the program to use on the internet in 2011. The password will be send in cleartext. (In a wired or WPA Enterprise protected wireless network you might be OK as long as all your traffic stays inhouse)

sftp is the secure replacement (based on ssh). `put` and `get` commands have the `-P` option to preserve the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your FTP client. I'm sure nearly all FTP clients have this option. For example, my favorite command-line FTP client, [Yafc](http://yafc.sourceforge.net/), lets you:

```
put -p filename
```

to `put` while `p`reserving file permissions.

Comment: can you do entire directories and their contents this way?